# Converting flattened hierarchical data from SQL Server into a structured JSON object with C#/Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, json, entity-framework

I am developing an MVC app that retrieves data from a table in SQL Server that is structured like so:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Id | Name   | Hierarchy   | Depth |
|-----------------------------------|
| 01 | Justin | /           |     0 |
| 02 | Chris  | /1          |     1 |
| 03 | Beth   | /1/1        |     2 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

The example data in the `Hierarchy` column is the string representation of the `hierarchyid` datatype, and the `Depth` column is computed using the `hierarchyid::GetLevel()` method.

Using Entity Framework 4.1, I have mapped the above table to this class:

```
public class Node {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HierarchyPath { get; set; } // String representation of the hierarchyid
    public int Depth { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use this information to display a graphical representation of the hierarchy to the user using the [JS Visualizations Toolkit](http://thejit.org/), which requires the data to be structured:

```
var node = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Justin'
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Chris',
        children: [{
            id: 3,
            name: 'Beth',
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm having trouble developing the logic to convert a list of my models into a structured JSON object. Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly does the "/1/1" in the hierarchy path work? Does it rely on ordering *by ID* of the children? (Imagine we had another node of depth 1 called "Foo" - how would we know whether Beth was a child of Foo or Chris?)

Comment: The path is independent of the ID column, but instead refers to the node's position within the hierarchy. A second node of depth 1 would have the path `/2`. The first child of `/2` would have a path of `/2/1`, then the second child `/2/2`, and so on. Better examples can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677195.aspx).

Comment: Ah, I see... I think. It's a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: I don't have time to fix the answer below right now, but given the extra information in the question, I suspect you want to keep a `Dictionary<int, HierarchicalNode>` rather than a `List<HierarchicalNode>` so that you're not relying on any ordering...

---

I would forget about the JSON representation to start with, and concentrate on building an in-memory POCO representation of the hierarchy. To do that, I'd use something like this:

```
class HierarchicalNode
{
    private readonly List<HierarchicalNode> children =
        new List<HierarchicalNode>();        
    public List<HierarchicalNode> Children { get { return children; } }

    private readonly string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } }

    private readonly int id;
    public int Id { get { return id; } }

    public HierarchicalNode(string name, int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then build up the tree like this:

```
// Make sure we get everything in a sensible order, parents before children
var query = context.Nodes.OrderBy(x => x.Depth);

var root = new HierarchicalNode("Root", 0);
foreach (var node in query)
{       
    var current = root;
    foreach (string part = node.HierarchyPath.Split(new[] {'/'},
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        int parsedPart = int.Parse(part);
        current = current.Children[parsedPart - 1];
    }
    current.Children.Add(new HierarchicalNode(node.Name, node.Id));
}
```

Comment: @Justin: Glad to help - sorry I couldn't actually give the full code; I assume you had to fix it up a bit, given the later information.

Comment: @JustinRusbatch : Thank you for posting this question. This is exactly what I wanted. Any chance of posting the solution?  it would be great if you can post the solution as well!!!!!!

Comment: @Justin According to your Answered tick, could you please give us the correct code. Unfornutaly This above code doesn't work correctly .

Comment: @Mohammad: Could you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work correctly"? Without providing any more information, it's hard to fix it. (And bear in mind this was nearly 9 years ago. I wouldn't be surprised if Justin doesn't have the code to hand any more.)

Comment: @Jon I Know this one is old but it won't work correctly. I put Error with data here a few minutes later

Comment: @Mohammad: I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @Jon thanks friend, Frankly I ask here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075884/
I don't know why there is nothing on the net for this problem

Comment: @Mohammad: That doesn't include a [mcve]. You haven't shown us your code, your input data, your expected results or your actual results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214935/discussion-between-mohammad-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I found myself with this problem and did not find the exact solution anywhere. I was able to build on @Jon's code and create the JSON like the OP posted by converting into POCO first. Posting here in case it helps someone.

The pre-requisite of this solution is that you know the maximum number of levels/depth your data has then you could do something like this:

```
  var nodesList = context.Nodes.OrderBy(x => x.Depth).ToList();
            var hierarchalData = new HierarchicalNode();
            foreach (var node in nodesList)
            {
                if (node.Depth == 1)
                {
                    // create the parent node
                    hierarchalData = new HierarchicalNode(node.Name, node.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    // create the child node object
                    var childNode = new HierarchicalNode(node.Name, node.Id);

                    // split the hierarchy into an array to get parent indexes
                    var splitHierarchy = node.HierarchyPath.Split("/").Skip(1).SkipLast(1).ToArray();
                    switch (node.Depth)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            hierarchalData.Children.Add(childNode);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            var lastParentIndex = Convert.ToInt32(splitHierarchy[splitHierarchy.Length - 2]) - 1;
                            hierarchalData.Children[lastParentIndex].Children.Add(childNode);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            var firstParentIndex = Convert.ToInt32(splitHierarchy[splitHierarchy.Length - 3]) - 1;
                            var lastParentIndex1 = Convert.ToInt32(splitHierarchy[splitHierarchy.Length - 2]) - 1;
                            hierarchalData.Children[firstParentIndex].Children[lastParentIndex1].Children.Add(childNode);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I know this approach is probably brute force but did the job for me.
Number of levels in my case was 7.