# NodeEntryCollection can't get sub node children

Tags: c#, dictionary, nodes

Taking suggestion from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425041/path-data-to-tree-like-data-structure), I'm populating a list view with paths array by converting it to N`odeEntryCollection` by

```
NodeEntryCollection nodes = new NodeEntryCollection();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    nodes.AddEntry(line, 0);
}
```

Now on double click list view item I'm using this.

```
private void filesList_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (filesList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

    if (filesList.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString() == "Folder")
    {
        string key = filesList.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        filesList.Clear();

        foreach (var item in nodes[key].Children) //Exception thrown here!
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.Key);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            if (item.Value.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                ListViewItem itmNew = new ListViewItem(item.Key, 0);
                itmNew.Tag = "Folder";
                filesList.Items.Add(itmNew);

            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItem itmNew = new ListViewItem(item.Key, objIconListManager.AddFileIcon(fileName));
                itmNew.Tag = "File";
                filesList.Items.Add(itmNew);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine on first directory and I see files from it but when I double click again on a subdirectory it throws:

> [KeyNotFoundException was unhandled]
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Please add the exception as text. The image url isn't working.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: *[KeyNotFoundException was unhandled] The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Still stuck here.

Comment: What is the value of `key` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: For example if I have following folder/subfolder `New WinRAR archive\New folder` when `key` is `New folder` it throws exception

Comment: Difficult to help w/o a full reproducing project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that according to the question [path data to tree like data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425041/path-data-to-tree-like-data-structure) your `NodeEntryCollection` is just a `Dictionary<string, NodeEntry>` with a bit of custom item addition logic, where `NodeEntry` itself is the pair of `string Key` and `NodeEntryCollection Children`.

`NodeEntryCollection nodes` is your root node. For example, fill it this way:

```
nodes.AddEntry("root", 0);
nodes.AddEntry("root/main", 0);
nodes.AddEntry("root/main/dev", 0);
```

At the moment `nodes` has only single element `"root"`. `Children` of `"root"` is also `NodeEntryCollection` with only single element `"main"` and so on.

Also you are probably filling the `filesList` by iterating `nodes`. So only `root` is displayed in the list. When you double-click it, in this line:

```
foreach (var item in nodes[key].Children)
```

`key` value is `"root"` and you successfully got a first (and single) item in the collection. After iterating through the `Children` the `main` is displayed in the list. Everything are okay.

However, when you doble-click `main`, you again go in this `foreach` and `key` value is `"main"`, but `nodes` has only single `"root"` key, and obviously `KeyNotFoundException` will be thrown. **Actually you need to iterate through the `Children` of the current selected node, which is  `"main"` now, not your root node.**

One way to do this is to track your current selected node.

```
NodeEntryCollection viewRoot;
```

Initially, for example at `nodes` filling, set it to you actual tree root node:

```
viewRoot = nodes;
```

Then in your event handler:

```
if (filesList.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString() == "Folder")
{
    string key = filesList.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    filesList.Clear();

    viewRoot = viewRoot[key].Children; // Set new view root

    //foreach (var item in nodes[key].Children) //Exception thrown here!
    foreach (var item in viewRoot) // iterate throught it
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.Key);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

        if (item.Value.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem itmNew = new ListViewItem(item.Key, 0);
            itmNew.Tag = "Folder";
            filesList.Items.Add(itmNew);

        }
        else
        {
            ListViewItem itmNew = new ListViewItem(item.Key, objIconListManager.AddFileIcon(fileName));
            itmNew.Tag = "File";
            filesList.Items.Add(itmNew);
        }
    }
}
```