# Converting flattened hierarchical data into a tree structured JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq, tree

I have a C# dictionary object which contains name of file and folder under which that file is available. I want to convert the data into hierarchical tree. Below is the data. How can I convert it into tree structured JSON.

i looked into this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945216/converting-flattened-hierarchical-data-from-sql-server-into-a-structured-json-ob) but I am not able to get the desired output.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+|
|  Name             | Path 
|------------------------------------------------|
| Kitchen supplies  |  Shopping / Housewares     |
| Groceries         |  Shopping / Housewares     |
| Cleaning supplies |  Shopping / Housewares     |
| Office supplies   |  Shopping / Housewares     |
| Retile kitchen    |  Shopping / Remodeling     |
| Ceiling           |  Shopping / Paint bedroom  |
| Walls             |  Shopping / Paint bedroom  |
| Misc              |  null                      |
| Other             |  Shopping                  | 
+-----------------------------------------------+|
```

**Should Generate output like:**

```
   {"text":".","children": [
    {
        Name:' Shopping',
        children:[{
            Name:'Housewares',
            children:[{
                Name:'Kitchen supplies',
                leaf:true,
            },{
                Name:'Groceries',
                leaf:true,
            },{
                Name:'Cleaning supplies',
                leaf:true,
            },{
                Name: 'Office supplies',
                leaf: true,
            }]
        }, {
            Name:'Remodeling',
            children:[{
                Name:'Retile kitchen',
                leaf:true,
            },{
                Name:'Paint bedroom',
                children: [{
                    Name: 'Ceiling',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    Name: 'Walls',
                    iconCls: 'Name',
                }]
            },
            {
                Name: 'Other',
                leaf: true
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        Name: 'Misc',
        leaf: true
    }
]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not getting desired output? What was wrong?

Comment: @Kuzgun: I am not sure how to go about it. And what is the best and most efficient way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in the example you linked to, there are two main tasks.  First, we need to get the data from the dictionary into a hierarchical form.  Once, we've done that, we can worry about serializing it to JSON.

So first thing, we need a `Node` class to represent the hierarchy:

```
class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Once we have that, we can go through the dictionary and build the tree.  (Note: in your desired JSON, you show `Paint bedroom` and `Other` as subordinate to `Remodeling`, while in your example dictionary data they are subordinate to `Shopping`.  I am assuming the JSON is correct in this case, so I changed the dictionary data accordingly as shown below.)

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Kitchen supplies", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Groceries", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Cleaning supplies", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Office supplies", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Retile kitchen", "Shopping / Remodeling");
dict.Add("Ceiling", "Shopping / Remodeling / Paint bedroom");
dict.Add("Walls", "Shopping / Remodeling / Paint bedroom");
dict.Add("Misc", null);
dict.Add("Other", "Shopping / Remodeling");

Node root = new Node();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    Node parent = root;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value))
    {
        Node child = null;
        foreach (string part in kvp.Value.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            string name = part.Trim();
            child = parent.Children.Find(n => n.Name == name);
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = new Node { Name = name };
                parent.Children.Add(child);
            }
            parent = child;
        }
    }
    parent.Children.Add(new Node { Name = kvp.Key });
}
```

Now that we have our tree, we can serialize it.  However, we need some special handling because your leaf nodes are rendered differently than non-leaf nodes in your JSON: leaf nodes have a `leaf` property and no `children` property, while the reverse is true for non-leaf nodes.  To handle this logic, we will need a custom `JsonConverter`.  (Just to clarify, I am using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) here-- your question did not mention a specific JSON serializer.)

```
class NodeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Node));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Node node = (Node)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("name", node.Name);
        if (node.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            jo.Add("leaf", true);
        }
        else
        {
            jo.Add("children", JArray.FromObject(node.Children, serializer));
        }
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

We can use the JsonConverter to serialize the tree to JSON like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new NodeConverter() },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "name": ".",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Shopping",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Housewares",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Kitchen supplies",
              "leaf": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Groceries",
              "leaf": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Cleaning supplies",
              "leaf": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Office supplies",
              "leaf": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Remodeling",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Retile kitchen",
              "leaf": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Paint bedroom",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Ceiling",
                  "leaf": true
                },
                {
                  "name": "Walls",
                  "leaf": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "Other",
              "leaf": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Misc",
      "leaf": true
    }
  ]
}
```

One other minor note: in your desired JSON above, you show the root node with a `text` property instead of a `name` property, which is inconsistent with all the other nodes.  I am assuming this was a mistake.  If it wasn't, you'll need to change the JsonConverter so that it has logic to output a `text` property in place of the `name` if the name is a dot (`.`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for such in-dept reply with example. I could not ask for more. Awesome answer.