# How to convert SQL Server data list into a structured JSON object with C# MVC4

Tags: c#, json, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC application that retrieves data from multiple tables in SQL Server.  The query builds a structured hierarchical JSON file for me that I embed in my d3.js tree view file.
This is all working great for me at the prototype level.  Now I need to build the JSON dynamically in C# and pass it to a view to consume.
I need assistance building the C# logic to convert data into a structured JSON object. 
I have reviewed this article but still need assistance [Converting flattened hierarchical data from SQL Server into a structured JSON object with C#/Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945216/converting-flattened-hierarchical-data-from-sql-server-into-a-structured-json-ob) .

Here is a link to JSfiddle.net of a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/hoopkjaz/d5Azm/ - it has the embedded JSON that my question is about starting on line 229.

As you can see the JSON can have up to 10 levels of children.  The JSON I am using here is the largest it will ever get.

Here is the tsql that creates the JSON

```
set nocount on

declare
  @sponsors table
  (num int,
   id int)

declare
  @customer_id int,
  @sponsor_id int,
  @sponsor_num int,
  @last_sponsor_id int,
  @last_customer_id int,
  @new_sponsor int,
  @tmp_num int,
  @tmp_id int,
  @json_text nvarchar(400);

declare data_cursor cursor for
with cte (customerid,
          thepath) as (
  SELECT customerid,
         convert(varbinary(max), customerid) as thepath
    FROM customers
    where customerid = 10013
    union all
    SELECT a.customerid,
         c.thepath + convert(varbinary(max), a.customerid) as thepath
    FROM customers a
         inner join cte c on
           a.sponsorid = c.customerid)
            select cus.customerid,
                   cus.sponsorid,
                   '{"ID": "' + convert(varchar(10),cus.customerid) + '",' +
            '"name": "' + 'cus.firstname ' + ' ' + 'cus.lastname' + '",' +
            '"fname": "' + cus.firstname + '",' +
            '"type": "' + case cus.customertypeid when 1 then 'C' else 'MP' end + '",' +
            '"phone": "' + '602-555-1212' + '",' +
            '"email": "' + 'dev@gmail.com' + '",' +
            '"paidranktxt": "' + isnull(pr.rankdescription,'') + '",' +
            '"ranktxt": "' + isnull(r.rankdescription,'') + '",' +
            '"PQV": "' + convert(varchar(10),isnull(pv.volume3,0)) + '",' +
            '"GQV": "' + convert(varchar(10),isnull(pv.volume5,0)) + '"' as json
            from cte
                  inner join customers cus
                 on cte.customerid = cus.customerid
                 and cus.customerstatusid <> 0
                   inner join periods per
                 on per.periodtypeid = 1
                 and per.periodid =
                 (select max(pv.periodid)
                    from periodvolumes pv
                   where pv.periodtypeid = 1)
               left join periodvolumes pv
                 on pv.customerid = cus.customerid
                 and per.periodid = pv.periodid
                 and per.periodtypeid = pv.periodtypeid
               left join ranks pr
                 on pv.paidrankid = pr.rankid
               left join ranks r
                 on pv.rankid = r.rankid
        order by cte.thepath;

    declare sponsor_cursor cursor for
      select num, id
        from @sponsors
       order by num desc;

    open data_cursor

    fetch next from  data_cursor
    into @customer_id,
         @sponsor_id,
         @json_text

    set @last_customer_id = 0;
    set @last_sponsor_id = 0;
    set @sponsor_num = 0;

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
      set @new_sponsor = 0;

      if @last_customer_id = @sponsor_id
        begin
          print ', "children": ['
          set @sponsor_num = @sponsor_num + 1
    --print 'Insert: ' + convert(varchar(10),@sponsor_num) + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),@last_customer_id)
          insert into @sponsors (num, id)
            select @sponsor_num, @last_customer_id
        end
      else if @last_sponsor_id = @sponsor_id
        print '},'

      else if @last_customer_id > 0
        begin
          print '}'

          open sponsor_cursor

          fetch next from  sponsor_cursor
            into @tmp_num,
                 @tmp_id

          while @@fetch_status = 0
            begin
    --print 'Number: ' + convert(varchar(10),@tmp_num)
    --print 'ID: ' + convert(varchar(10),@tmp_id)

              if @sponsor_id = @tmp_id
                begin
                  print ','
                  set @new_sponsor = @tmp_num
                  break
                end
              else
                begin
                  set @sponsor_num = @sponsor_num - 1
                  print '] }'
                end

              fetch next from  sponsor_cursor
                into @tmp_num,
                     @tmp_id
            end
          close sponsor_cursor;
        end

      if @new_sponsor > 0
        delete from @sponsors where num > @new_sponsor

    --print 'Sponsor: ' + convert(varchar(10),@sponsor_id)
      print @json_text

      set @last_customer_id = @customer_id;
      set @last_sponsor_id = @sponsor_id;

      fetch next from data_cursor
      into @customer_id,
           @sponsor_id,
           @json_text
    end

    close data_cursor;

    deallocate data_cursor;

       begin
          print '}'

          open sponsor_cursor

          fetch next from  sponsor_cursor
            into @tmp_num,
                 @tmp_id

          if @@fetch_status <> 0
            print '] }'

          while @@fetch_status = 0
            begin
              if @sponsor_id = @tmp_id
                begin
                  print '] }'
                  set @new_sponsor = @tmp_num
                  break
                end
              else
                begin
                  set @sponsor_num = @sponsor_num - 1
                  print '] }'
                end

              fetch next from  sponsor_cursor
                into @tmp_num,
                     @tmp_id
            end
          close sponsor_cursor;
        end
```

Here is the class that should hold the list

```
public class Node
    {
        public Node() {
       Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Paidranktxt { get; set; }
    public string Ranktxt { get; set; }
    public string PQV { get; set; }
    public string GQV { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method I use to pull the list from SQL

```
 public static IEnumerable<Node> GetNode(int? customerId)
    {
        try
        {

            const string query = @"  SQL from above goes here";                           

            var jsonResult = TransactionManager.Current.Entities.Database.SqlQuery<Node>(query,new SqlParameter("CustomerID", customerId));                                                                          
            return jsonResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log the error in Elmah
            e.LogToElmah();
            return null;
        }
```

Here is an example of the SQL before formatting.  We use the sponsorid to determine the children

```
ID  sponsorid name  fname   type phone        email    paidranktxt ranktxt  PQV GQV
10013 10000   first Brian   MP   602-555-1234 d@m.com  TLeader      TL  0.00    13740.00
10624 10013   first Brian   MP   602-555-1234 d@m.com  TLeader      TL  0.00    13740.00
10975 10624   first Brian   MP   602-555-1234 d@m.com  TLeader      TL  0.00    13740.00
```

Comment: Might this help? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I may have asked this wrong since it is my first time.  I actually have the TSQL down.  My issue is doing the same logic in C# and passing it as a JSON object to my mvc view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if I understand correctly you will stop using the t-sql code to generate JSON, and instead want to convert a hierarchy of Node objects into JSON using C#.

Assuming that is correct, my suggestion is to simply use [JSON.Net](http://json.net), and if you are using WebAPI (ie you will get the data using javascript in an async request for example), then this will be as simple as having a controller with an action like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes() {
   IEnumerable<Node> nodes;
   ...
   // code to get Nodes from DB goes here
   ...

   return nodes;
}
```

To configure JSON.Net to be used in WebAPI, something like this in your Global.asax will work:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
var index = config.Formatters.IndexOf(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
config.Formatters[index] = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        //ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
    }
};
```

Finally to convert your flat data structure into a hierarchical one:

```
class Program
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class NhNode
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SponsorId { get; set; }
    }

    static Node ConvertToHierarchy(NhNode nhnode, IEnumerable<NhNode> nodes)
    {
        var node = new Node()
        {
            ID = nhnode.ID
        };

        foreach (var item in nodes.Where(p => p.SponsorId == nhnode.ID))
        {
            node.Children.Add(ConvertToHierarchy(item, nodes));
        }

        return node;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<NhNode> nhnodes = new List<NhNode>() {
            new NhNode() { ID = 10013, SponsorId = 10000 },
            new NhNode() { ID = 10624, SponsorId = 10013 },
            new NhNode() { ID = 10975, SponsorId = 10624 }
        };

        var node = ConvertToHierarchy(nhnodes.First(p => p.SponsorId == 10000), nhnodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: rfernandes thanks for the reply.  You are correct in your analysis of my needs.  In my C# GetNodes,  when I do it like you suggest the returned nodes are not formatted in the hierarchy needed.  Take a look at the js fiddle file and you will see the format needed.  I need a c# class that will do the same logic that my TSQL is doing.  This article explains it but I can't get it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945216/converting-flattened-hierarchical-data-from-sql-server-into-a-structured-json-ob?lq=1

Comment: Hopefully my latest edit covers what you need - converting a flat list into a hierarchical one - I've simplified the classes to reduce code size.

Comment: This looks like it will work.  I will try it out. I will probably have some questions along the way if that is ok.

Comment: This works great thank you!  I do have a quick question though.  When I change this to grab the SQL instead of hard coding the values I run into one issue with this line  var node = ConvertToHierarchy(nhnodes.First(p => p.SponsorId == 10000), nhnodes)...what would the 10000 be?  what parameter do I place there?

Comment: That is the topmost object of the hierarchy - if you use ID instead of sponsorid to identify that object, you can of course change that to something like var node = ConvertToHierarchy(nhnodes.First(p => p.ID == 10013), nhnodes).

Comment: Yup I see that but in this case I don't want to hard code the number because I could come in anywhere in the tree.  For example a user with the id = 21258 could log into the system to get their tree. They are way down the stack and don't have the 10013 as their sponsorid

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you can certainly substitute "10013" for a variable name? For example p=>p.ID==myvar