# How to transform list of hierarchyid into a binary tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, binary-tree, hierarchyid

I am working on a multi-level marketing (binary) which looks like this:

(but the binary tree is not required to be perfect. A node can have 0-2 child)

[image]

My problem is the data that I fetch from the database is flat list.
[image]
[image]

Notice that I am using [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) (sql server 2014)

Basically the `TextNode` column is like a breadcrumb.

every slash `/` represents a `level`.

If I have TextNode of `/1/` as root. then every node that starts with `/1/` belongs to that root which are `/1/`, `/1/1/` and `/1/1/1/` (the root node is included which will be the level 0)

I've tried the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945216/converting-flattened-hierarchical-data-from-sql-server-into-a-structured-json-ob) in this question but its not working.

How can I transform the flatlist to a Binary Tree so that I can easily traverse and display it on a screen?

Im using C#, ASP MVC 5, SQL Server 2014 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I implement exactly this code According to Alex implementation but as is mentioned in some case it didn't work correctly .. have a look to my Image and my code (which copied from Alex post) [data in the database are correct but in tree view seems some problems ]

```
public class Row : IRow<string>
{
    public string TextNode { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
    public long Id { get; }
    public string FIN { get; }
    public Row(string textNode, string userName, long id, string fin)
    {
        FIN = fin;
        Id = id;
        TextNode = textNode;
        Value = userName;
    }
}

public interface IRow<out T>
{
    string TextNode { get; }
    long Id { get; }
    string FIN { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private struct NodeDescriptor
    {
        public int Level { get; }
        public int ParentIndex { get; }

        public NodeDescriptor(IRow<T> row)
        {
            var split = row.TextNode.Split(new[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Level = split.Length;
            ParentIndex = split.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(split[split.Length - 2]) - 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    public T title { get; }
    public long Id { get; }
    public string FIN { get; }
    public List<TreeNode<T>> children { get; }

    private TreeNode(T value, long id, string fin)
    {
        Id = id;
        FIN = fin;
        title = value;
        children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public static TreeNode<T> Parse(IReadOnlyList<IRow<T>> rows)
    {
        if (rows.Count == 0)
            return null;
        var result = new TreeNode<T>(rows[0].Value, rows[0].Id, rows[0].FIN);
        FillParents(new[] { result }, rows, 1, 1);
        return result;
    }

    private static void FillParents(IList<TreeNode<T>> parents, IReadOnlyList<IRow<T>> rows, int index, int currentLevel)
    {
        var result = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
        for (int i = index; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var descriptor = new NodeDescriptor(rows[i]);
            if (descriptor.Level != currentLevel)
            {
                FillParents(result, rows, i, descriptor.Level);
                return;
            }
            var treeNode = new TreeNode<T>(rows[i].Value, rows[i].Id, rows[i].FIN);
            parents[descriptor.ParentIndex].children.Add(treeNode);
            result.Add(treeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]g

this is also my JSON output for more information :

```
{"title":"Earth","Id":32,"FIN":"FIN","children":[{"title":"Europe","Id":33,"FIN":"FIN001","children":[{"title":"France","Id":35,"FIN":"FIN001001","children":[{"title":"Paris","Id":36,"FIN":"FIN001001001","children":[]},{"title":"Brasilia","Id":41,"FIN":"FIN002001001","children":[]},{"title":"Bahia","Id":42,"FIN":"FIN002001002","children":[]}]},{"title":"Spain","Id":38,"FIN":"FIN001002","children":[{"title":"Madrid","Id":37,"FIN":"FIN001002001","children":[{"title":"Salvador","Id":43,"FIN":"FIN002001002001","children":[]}]}]},{"title":"Italy","Id":45,"FIN":"FIN001003","children":[]},{"title":"Germany","Id":48,"FIN":"FIN001004","children":[]},{"title":"test","Id":10049,"FIN":"FIN001005","children":[]}]},{"title":"South America","Id":34,"FIN":"FIN002","children":[{"title":"Brazil","Id":40,"FIN":"FIN002001","children":[{"title":"Morano","Id":47,"FIN":"FIN001003001","children":[]}]}]},{"title":"Antarctica","Id":39,"FIN":"FIN003","children":[{"title":"McMurdo Station","Id":44,"FIN":"FIN003001","children":[]}]}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple implementation (assuming that Nodes are in the right order), which may be enhanced in multiple ways

```
public interface IRow<out T>
{
    string TextNode { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private struct NodeDescriptor
    {
        public int Level { get; }
        public int ParentIndex { get; }

        public NodeDescriptor(IRow<T> row)
        {
            var split = row.TextNode.Split(new [] {"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Level = split.Length;
            ParentIndex = split.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(split[split.Length - 2]) - 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    public T Value { get; }
    public List<TreeNode<T>> Descendants { get; }

    private TreeNode(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Descendants = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public static TreeNode<T> Parse(IReadOnlyList<IRow<T>> rows)
    {
        if (rows.Count == 0)
            return null;
        var result = new TreeNode<T>(rows[0].Value);
        FillParents(new[] {result}, rows, 1, 1);
        return result;
    }

    private static void FillParents(IList<TreeNode<T>> parents, IReadOnlyList<IRow<T>> rows, int index, int currentLevel)
    {
        var result = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
        for (int i = index; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var descriptor = new NodeDescriptor(rows[i]);
            if (descriptor.Level != currentLevel)
            {
                FillParents(result, rows, i, descriptor.Level);
                return;
            }
            var treeNode = new TreeNode<T>(rows[i].Value);
            parents[descriptor.ParentIndex].Descendants.Add(treeNode);
            result.Add(treeNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public class Row : IRow<string>
{
    public string TextNode { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public Row(string textNode, string userName)
    {
        TextNode = textNode;
        Value = userName;
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IRow<string>[] rows =
        {
            new Row("/", "Ahmed"),
            new Row("/1/", "Saeed"),
            new Row("/2/", "Amjid"),
            new Row("/1/1/", "Noura"),
            new Row("/2/1/", "Noura01"),
            new Row("/2/2/", "Reem01"),
            new Row("/1/1/1", "Under_noura")
        };

        var tree = TreeNode<string>.Parse(rows);
        PrintTree(tree);
    }

    private static void PrintTree<T>(TreeNode<T> tree, int level = 0)
    {
        string prefix = new string('-', level*2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", prefix, tree.Value);
        foreach (var node in tree.Descendants)
        {
            PrintTree(node, level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any examples of those cases, please? This answer is somewhat old and I could do better, but it should work anyway, just sort rows before parsing (by number of `/` ascending, then by string value)

Comment: Thank you so much for your follow up. as you said, I have posted that